# React native: Eject expo to expo bare project to run by react native cli got error

Tags: react-native, expo

I am beginner on react native so to create project i used [expo](https://expo.io/learn). 
After creating project and use navigation and a few js page i want to compile my project on android emulator.

so i installed react native:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

and configured other dependencies like `Python2, a JDK, and Android Studio` according it's [official site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started).

To testing i create a new project with `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` command and then i compiled it's on emulator by `npx react-native run-android` command. finally the test app runs on emulator.

Now i want to compile my main app that i ejected from expo to **expo bare**.

```
expo eject
```

after ejecting i run npx react-native run-android. This is complete output:

```
\AuditMngm> npx react-native run-android
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-reanimated (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-reanimated")
  - react-native-screens (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-screens")This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.       
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1766 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
 unimodules-core@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\@unimodules\core
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter
 expo-app-loader-provider@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-app-loader-provider
 expo-constants@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-constants
 expo-error-recovery@1.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-error-recovery
 expo-file-system@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-file-system
 expo-font@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-font   
 expo-keep-awake@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-keep-awake
 expo-linear-gradient@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-linear-gradient
 expo-location@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-location
 expo-permissions@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-permissions
 expo-sqlite@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-sqlite
 expo-web-browser@8.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\expo-web-browser
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-camera-interface
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-constants-interface
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-face-detector-interface
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-file-system-interface
 unimodules-font-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-font-interface
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-image-loader-interface
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-permissions-interface
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.0.0 from F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\node_modules\unimodules-task-manager-interface

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal. 
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then 
remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo-error-recovery', ':expo-permissions'

> Task :app:installDebug
04:13:39 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
04:13:39 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1 
04:13:39 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_XL_API_27(AVD) - 8.1.0' for app:debug
04:13:39 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'       
04:13:39 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
04:13:39 D/ddms: Reading file permision of F:\SafaProject\ReactNative\AuditMngm\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
04:13:39 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"  
04:13:42 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
04:13:42 V/ddms: execute: returning
04:13:42 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
04:13:42 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
04:13:42 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
471 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 470 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.auditproject/.MainActivity }
```

But i got error on emulator:

[image]

To test that every configuration is ok i create `ExpoBare` project and run it. Everything was ok and test project was completely compiled and started on android emulator But my project got above error.

What is your suggestion?

**Update**

I also run my project like above on liteLinux but unfortunately i got same error.

Comment: I do that but it does not work @AkhilNayak

Comment: There is no error https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YTPt2NF4Qc/ @AkhilNayak

Comment: I deleted `node_modules` and run `npm install` again. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YCvSjwNvtH/ @AkhilNayak

Comment: After deleting `node_modules` and run `npm install` and `npx react-native run-android` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KkhjS3Rsn5/ i still got above error @AkhilNayak

Comment: Did you solve it? How?

Comment: No i didn't . I create project with react-native-cli and i do not use expo @ehijon